# Spliting a DataFrame column to columns with regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a DataFrame with two columns the second one has following format :

```
1 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 0.0000e+00} {y-velocity 4.4010e-02} {z-velocity 9.5681e-04} {energy 1.1549e-07} }
2 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 7.8788e-04} {y-velocity 1.2617e+01} {z-velocity 9.0445e-04} {energy 4.5605e-06} }
3 {{continuity 2.3250e-01} {x-velocity 1.6896e-03} {y-velocity 1.2536e-02} {z-velocity 9.8980e-03} {energy 3.4032e-06} }
4 {{continuity 8.0243e-02} {x-velocity 2.2180e-03} {y-velocity 1.3189e-02} {z-velocity 1.0225e-02} {energy 4.6336e-07} }
5 {{continuity 7.0923e-02} {x-velocity 2.2674e-03} {y-velocity 1.2308e-02}
```

And I'm trying to use regex to split it into columns, by getting the first number, then getting all the numbers in between the brackets "{}" and give them the following names:

```
names=['iter', 'x', 'x-vel', 'y-vel', 'z-vel', 'energy']
```

However I just don't seem to make the regular expression work, here's what i'm doing in a simple example:

**Input**

```
>>> a = "1 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 0.0000e+00} {y-velocity 4.4010e-02} {z-velocity 9.5681e-04} {energy 1.1549e-07} }"
>>> re.findall("(\d*) {*\{\D*(.*?)\}", a)
```

**Result**

```
 >>> [('1', '1.0000e+00'), ('', '0.0000e+00'), ('', '4.4010e-02'), ('', '9.5681e-04'), ('', '1.1549e-07')]
```

As you can see my regex keeps looking for a number for every {} occurrence, but I don't want that to happen, how to do so?

**Expected Behavior**

```
 >>> [('1'), ('1.0000e+00'), ('0.0000e+00'), ('4.4010e-02'), ('9.5681e-04'), ('1.1549e-07')]
```

When my regular expression works, I'm trying to assign all the columns with a line that would look something like this:

```
df[names] = df.first.str.extract(r'(\d*) {*\{\D*(.*?)\}', expand=True)
```

I'm really new to dataframes, is this the correct approach for this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make a series from some data in the question.

```
import pandas as pd    

data = pd.Series('''\
1 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 0.0000e+00} {y-velocity 4.4010e-02} {z-velocity 9.5681e-04} {energy 1.1549e-07} }
2 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 7.8788e-04} {y-velocity 1.2617e+01} {z-velocity 9.0445e-04} {energy 4.5605e-06} }
3 {{continuity 2.3250e-01} {x-velocity 1.6896e-03} {y-velocity 1.2536e-02} {z-velocity 9.8980e-03} {energy 3.4032e-06} }
4 {{continuity 8.0243e-02} {x-velocity 2.2180e-03} {y-velocity 1.3189e-02} {z-velocity 1.0225e-02} {energy 4.6336e-07} }'''
          .split('\n'))
print(data)
```

---

```
0    1 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 0.0000e...
1    2 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 7.8788e...
2    3 {{continuity 2.3250e-01} {x-velocity 1.6896e...
3    4 {{continuity 8.0243e-02} {x-velocity 2.2180e...
dtype: object
       0
```

The first option is a simple regex to find all numbers in order. Use `extractall` to find every match in each string. This may be good enough. You still have to name the columns, which isn't hard. This will have a `MultiIndex` (which is a little more advanced), since each match could have multiple groups (but this regex only has one group), hence the need to `.unstack()` it.

```
print(data.str.extractall(r'(\d[\d.e+-]*)').unstack())
```

---

```
match  0           1           2           3           4           5
0      1  1.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.4010e-02  9.5681e-04  1.1549e-07
1      2  1.0000e+00  7.8788e-04  1.2617e+01  9.0445e-04  4.5605e-06
2      3  2.3250e-01  1.6896e-03  1.2536e-02  9.8980e-03  3.4032e-06
3      4  8.0243e-02  2.2180e-03  1.3189e-02  1.0225e-02  4.6336e-07
```

Alternatively, you can use a named groups regex. This is a fairly straightforward template to build from one of the strings. This will put the names from the regex into the columns. But the names must be valid Python identifiers. (`x_vel`, not `x-vel`). But this is probably what you want anyway, since it lets you access the columns as attrs (like `df.x_vel` instead of `df['x-vel']`). This `(?P<foo>...)` named group syntax is all explained in the `re` module docs.

```
print(
    data.str.extract(r'(?P<iter>\d+) {{continuity (?P<x>[^}]+)} {x-velocity (?P<x_vel>[^}]+)} {y-velocity (?P<y_vel>[^}]+)} {z-velocity (?P<z_vel>[^}]+)} {energy (?P<energy>[^}]+)} }',
                     expand=False))
```

---

```
  iter           x       x_vel       y_vel       z_vel      energy
0    1  1.0000e+00  0.0000e+00  4.4010e-02  9.5681e-04  1.1549e-07
1    2  1.0000e+00  7.8788e-04  1.2617e+01  9.0445e-04  4.5605e-06
2    3  2.3250e-01  1.6896e-03  1.2536e-02  9.8980e-03  3.4032e-06
3    4  8.0243e-02  2.2180e-03  1.3189e-02  1.0225e-02  4.6336e-07
```

Note that we're using `extract` instead of `extractall` here because there are multiple groups in the regex itself.